# Looking for information on cloud composer stable release?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

At present cloud composer in Beta release, we want to use it on our production environment.  Any information on the timelines of its stable release and when will they provide full support?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Cloud Composer release notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#july_19_2018_composer-100-airflow-190), this product launched as General Availability yesterday. You can have a look at all the changes that came with the GA launch in that link, and also at the implications and changes between a beta and a GA release in the [GCP Launch Stages documentation](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages).

In any case, for the future, I recommend you to stay updated about this type of changes through the product's Release Notes page, the [GCP Big Data blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/#) (where most news and relevant changes are published, although I see no announcement for Composer yet) and the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) (where you will find information about feature requests and other public issues).

Comment: If the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!